# A better way updating a nested XML

Tags: xml, flex4

I have a few lines of code:

```
 lev = arrInfo[1]
 xml = sxml;
 switch(lev){
 case 0: xml = sxml;
 break;
 case 1: var xl:XML = arrInfo[0];
 xml.sublevels = xl;
 break;
 case 2: xl = arrInfo[0];
 xml.sublevels.sublevel.sublevels = xl;
 break;
 case 3: xl = arrInfo[0];                                                                             
 xml.sublevels.sublevel.sublevels.sublevel.sublevels = xl;
 break;
}
```

In the switch statement, it checks what level of sublevels the xl XML should be attached to and based on the level, it goes to attach it. So, if level three, that means the xl should substitute the sublevels in that level. In case 3: the xl substitutes the sublevels in the sublevel node of the (level-1) sublevels node and if I have case 4: then the xl should replace the sublevels of the sublevel node of the (4-1) sublevels. That would look something like this:

```
 case 4: xl = arrInfo[0];                                                                             
 xml.sublevels.sublevel.sublevels.sublevel.sublevels.sublevel.sublevels = xl;
```

However, that means I have to do this manually if I know the number of sublevels in the nested XML, but this will be so much of work if the levels were 20 or someone adds a new level that was not manually checked in the switch statement.

Anyone knows how I can solve this problem?

Comment: This looks convoluted. Why do you need to this ? You could loop through the descendants of your xml recursively and add another xml node using [appendChild()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#appendChild%28%29), but maybe there is an easier way to solve this. What kind of data are you saving ? Does it need to be so nested ?

Comment: @George Profenza, the easier way is to ensure that the xml is the same modified. i already got that solved but i do not know how to make that obvious to the stackflow community :(

Comment: cool. you should be able to close/delete your own question